# Symfony2 errors on form field and parent

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Is it possible to have validation on the form but keep it on the field at that same time? I am trying to have all my errors display at the top of the page but I would also like to have a red border around the error field. Also, each of my errors on the top should have a link that gives focus on the field that has that error.

If I use `{{ form_errors(form.title) }}`, I don't access to `{{ form_errors(form) }}`. If I use `error_bubbling => true` on the field then I don't access to `{{ form_errors(form.title) }}`. I was thinking of building my errors display in my controller, but if I do that, I'm losing Twig's functionality.

Comment: Have you thought about assigning any errors to a variable in your controller and passing that to the view to use for displaying your errors?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did to make it work, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I'm currenly using, I don't know if it's a good one. Personnaly I would rather do it all in Twig but I couldn't find a better way.

**DefaultController.php** : I'm passing the $errors to my view.

```
$errors = array();
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bind($this->getRequest());
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        ...
    } else {
        foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                $errors[$form->getName().'_'.$child->getName()] = substr($child->getErrorsAsString(),7);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**template.html.twig**

```
{% if errors|length > 0 %}
    <ul>
    {% for key, error in errors %}
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="{{ key }}" class="errorClick">{{ error }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}

{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %} {% if errors|length > 0 %}class="error"{% endif %} />
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

**script.js**

```
$('.errorClick').click(function() {
    $('#'+$(this).attr('data-id')).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Customize your `form_row` block to not display error

   ```
   {% block form_row %}
   <div class="form-group{% if errors|length == 1 %} has-error{% endif %}">
           {{ form_label(form, label|default(null)) }}
           {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'form-control' } } ) }}
   </div>
   {% endblock form_row %}
   ```
2. Customize `form_errors` to be clickable. You can create a jQuery function to listen for clicks on `li`. In the function get the `id` of the clicked `li` remove *RelatedField* to get the field id

   ```
   {% block form_errors -%}
   {% if errors|length > 0 -%}
   <ul id="allErrors">
   {%- for error in errors -%}
   <li id="RelatedField{{ error.id }}">{{ error.message }}</a></li>
   {%- endfor -%}
   </ul>
   {%- endif %}
   {%- endblock form_errors %}
   ```

**References**

- How to Customize Form Rendering - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't because the error are on the form or on the field. I don't have access to the errors in form_row and on form.